# Proving an integral with random variables tends to $0$

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $\{X_{n}\}$ be a sequence of random variables. Prove that
>
> $$\lim_{m\to\infty} \int_{\{|X_{n}|>m\}} |X_{n}|\mathop{d\mathbb{P}} =
>  0 $$
>
> if and only if the following two conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1) $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}|X_{n}| < \infty$
>
> 2) For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta_{\epsilon} > 0$ such
>   that
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(A) < \delta_{\epsilon} \implies \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}
>  \int_{A} |X_{n}| \mathop{d\mathbb{P}} < \epsilon.$$

I'm studying for my exam, and this is a practice question that I have been stuck on for a few days now. Intuitively the result makes sense. It reminds me of the notion of $\epsilon-\delta$ convergence, but with random variables.

I am not so sure how to prove it, and I cannot even find any similar problems online to guide me.

Comment: I believe this is known as uniform integrability. Perhaps that will help your search.

Comment: Can you prove one direction?  For example $\implies$?  What about for all $m>0$: $$ E[|X_n|] \leq m + E[|X_n| 1_{|X_n|>m}]$$

Comment: I am not so sure how to prove one direction even with your hint. I guess indicator functions may be helpful here. @Math1000's hint has helped me a bit and I am now reading similar things online.

Comment: @Michael Am I supposed to use dominated convergence theorem on that?

Comment: The last term $E[|X_n|1_{|X_n|>m}]$ is in fact the integral in question, we know that for sufficiently large $m$ this value is smaller than 1.

Comment: For the opposite direction $\impliedby$, you can use the Markov inequality and item 2.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question a bit. The condition should read $\lim_{M\to\infty} \left( \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{\{|X_{n}|>M\}} |X_{n}|\mathop{d\mathbb{P}} \right) = 0$ instead. A full proof can be found here: https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/uniform_integrability.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is not stated correctly. Instead of $\lim_{m\to \infty} \int_{|X_n|>m} |X_n|dP \to 0$ the condition should be $\lim_{m\to \infty} sup_n \int_{|X_n|>m} |X_n|dP \to 0$.

Suppose 1) and 2) hold. Then $mP(|X_n| >m) \leq E|X_n| \leq C$ where $C$ is the supremum in 1). Hence $P(|X_n| >m) \leq \frac C  m <\delta_{\epsilon}$ provided $m >\frac C {\delta_{\epsilon}}$. By 2) with $A=(|X_n| >m)$ this implies $\int_{|X_n| >m} |X_n| dP <\epsilon$.

Converse part: assume that  $\int_{|X_n| >m} |X_n| dP <\epsilon$ for  $m \geq m_0$. Then $E|X_n| = \int_{|X_n| >m_0} |X_n| dP+\int_{|X_n| \leq m_0} |X_n| dP<\epsilon +m_0$ so 1) holds. For 2) write $\int_A |X_n| dP$ as $\int_{A\cap B} |X_n| dP+\int_{A\cap B^{c}} |X_n| dP$ where $B=(|X_n| >m)$. Now the first term does not exceed $\int_{|X_n| >m_0} |X_n| dP$ which is $ <\epsilon$ . On the other hand the second term does not exceed $m_0 P(A)$. So we only have to choose $\delta $ such that $m_0\delta <\epsilon$ to finish  the proof.

Comment: Again you need the limit condition to be uniform for the proof to hold.

Comment: @XiaohaiZhang Thank you It was wishful thinking on my part -:) I just assumed that OP had the right statement.